# Difference between ** and * in 3d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Both the codes shown below give the same output i.e for **a and *a (in `printf`). Why is that?

I am not very good with multi dimensional arrays, I have tried various blogs to understand but still fail to. I dont get how is the output same for both the cases. Thank you in advance.

THE OUTPUT FOR BOTH THE CASES IS 
abcdefghijklm

```
// CODE 1
int main() 
{

  char a[2][3][3] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 
                    'h','i','j','k','l','m'};
  printf("%s ", **a); 
  return 0; 
}
```

///code 2

int main() 
    {

```
  char a[2][3][3] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 
                    'h','i','j','k','l','m'};
  printf("%s ", *a); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I just see one case.

Comment: And what is the output in both cases?

Comment: Sorry, please check again.. I am not able to indent the code properly on stackoverflow. that is why posted one case and wrote in brackets that the difference is only inside printf. I have posted both cases now . Thank you

Comment: But you still haven't said what the output is. Why is this such a struggle?

Comment: This is not a properly terminated C string, so the output of that `printf` is undefined behaviour. This code doesn't make any sense at all. If you have a multi-dimensional array then you need to *iterate over it and display individual elements*.

Comment: @Bathsheba I added it . Sorry not everyone is an expert sir. I am new to this.

Comment: @tadman: There are fewer initializers than there are array elements, so the remaining elements are initialized to 0.  `a` does contain a properly terminated string.  Just maybe not intentionally.

Comment: @JohnBode I'm not sure that's the case if this is anywhere but `main()`.

Comment: @tadman: 6.7.9/21 - "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Comment: @JohnBode Good clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun one.

Remember that array elements are laid out contiguously - `a` looks something like this in memory:

```
   +---+
a: |'a'| a[0][0][0]
   +---+ 
   |'b'| a[0][0][1]
   +---+
   |'c'| a[0][0][2]
   +---+
   |'d'| a[0][1][0]
   +---+
   |'e'| a[0][1][1]
   +---+
   |'f'| a[0][1][2]
   +---+
   |'g'| a[0][2][0]
   +---+
   |'i'| a[0][2][1]
   +---+
   |'j'| a[0][2][2]
   +---+
   |'k'| a[1][0][0]
   +---+
   |'l'| a[1][0][1]
   +---+
   |'m'| a[1][0][2]
   +---+
   | 0 | a[1][1][0]
   +---+
   | 0 | a[1][1][1]
   +---+
    ...
```

Since you provided fewer initializers than the array was sized to hold (12 vs. 18), the remaining elements are initialized to 0 (this is important later on).

First, some background on arrays:

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The array subscript operation `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (not bytes!) from that address and dereference the result.  This means that `*a == *(a + 0) == a[0]`.

So, how does that apply to your code?

The *expression* `a` has type "2-element array of 3-element array of 3-element array of `char`".  If `a` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, that expression "decays" to type "pointer to 3-element array of 3-element array of `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array - `&a[0]`.

The expression `*a` dereferences that pointer, and the type of the expression is "3-element array of 3-element array of `char`".  Again, this expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operands, so it is converted to "pointer to 3-element array of `char`", and the value is the address of the first element of the array, or `&(*a)`.  Since `*a == a[0]`, this can also be seen as `&a[0][0]`.

The expression `**a` dereferences the result of `*a` (which had type "pointer to 3-element array of `char`"), and the type of the expression is "3-element array of `char`".  Again, this expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so it "decays" to type "pointer to `char`".

Which, coincidentally, is what `%s` expects.  The `%s` conversion specifier expects its argument to have type `char *` and to point to the first in a sequence of characters followed by a 0-valued terminator.  Remember earlier when I said the remaining 6 elements of the array would be initialized to 0?  Perhaps without meaning to, you've stored a *string* in `a`.

So, that's why you get the output you do with `**a`.  But why does `*a` work as well?

The address of an array is the same as the address of the first element of the array - `&a[0] == &a[0][0] == &a[0][0][0]` (which you can see from the ASCII art above).  The *type* of `*a` is wrong - `char (*)[3]` instead of `char *` - so strictly speaking the behavior is undefined, but its *value* (at least its logical value) is the same as `**a`.  Different pointer types may have different representations, so there may be a platform out there where the representation of a `char (*)[3]` may be different from a `char *` such that this code won't work.  However, on platforms like `x86`, all pointer types have the same representation, so the value of `*a` is interpreted the same way as the value of `**a`.

Comment: This is so good.. thank you for taking the time to answer this in such detail... cheers.